# How would I go about editing a meteor package I added?

Tags: meteor

Specifically, I just want to remove a `console.log` line from my ChartsJS file, since it kind of slows down my app just a little bit.

I found the file responsible in `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/packages` path. The changes work right after I save, but then revert back to original without the changes, so the changes I make are only temporary.

Note that the packages I use are from AtmosphereJS.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking... you are using an atmosphere package that you didn't author, but you want to change it. Is that right?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the procedure for modifying an existing package, and optionally getting your changes integrated back into the original:

1. Open an issue on github and let the maintainer know what's up.
2. Fork the code, and add make your modifictions. Keep this version as a [local package](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages).
3. Submit a pull request for the changes.

If all goes well, your PR will be accepted and everyone can benefit from the change. In the worst case, you'll still have a local copy that you can use in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not so much that there is anything wrong with the code. I just want to change something very minor only for my app because the problem is arising as a result of the way I have coded my app. Would using github solve this problem also?

Comment: In that case, just follow the steps from my post on local pacakges (from step 2) - it's your exact use case. You don't need to fork the package, just get a copy of the code, modify it, and run your own local version.